# Do all Blu-Ray writers write dual layer discs?

Tags: optical-drive, blu-ray

I would like to buy a BR writer. My question is simple: do all the models write BD-R DL or do I have to pay attention like for DVD burners?

All the products, from all brands, I found so far on some websites, eBay included, don't tell **anything** about support for 50GB discs, so this makes me think all support DL.

Is that true?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all burners support BD-R DL. Most do these days but make sure you check before ordering.

Comment: How can you tell? (Other than the mfgr's website telling you explicitly)?